# Locating items in space drifting together

Tags: space, space-travel

A bunch of cargo got sucked out of a spaceship during a depressurization event. Mostly crates and barrels of medium size liftable by a human without a forklift.

Now that cargo was a valuable equipement with a significant dollar value attached to it and naturally some of the containers had tracker beacons that would periodically transmit their position allowing to locate them in the endless vastness of space.

What are the chances that many years later the crates and barrels will remain in close enough proximity from each other that a ship of space janitors would be able to find most of them? Maybe attracted by whatever small gravity field they produce?

Or would they drift apart? In that case would it be possible to triangulate the position of unmarked cargo if the space janitors had enough data from several beacons?

Comment: Exactly where did this event take place? Deep space? Planetary orbit? Oort cloud? Midway between two galaxies gravity will have little effect on trajectories. If the event happened in a planetary orbit, however....

Comment: If ship/cargo owners were smart they would try to determine the orbits of the cargo as soon as reasonably possible. Once orbit for each crate is determined,  it's going to be much easier to find later.  e.g. Voyager probes. Unless a forces acts upon it of course.

Comment: pedantic nitpick: technically the cargo was *blown* out of the spaceship, not sucked.

Comment: @Michael Something drawn into motion by the force imposed by a vacuum is sucked (so says my vacuum and every water pump I've ever owned). "Blown" would be appropriate if the cause of motion was a force behind the cargo (away from the vacuum) such as that caused by detonating explosives. In other words, the air isn't the cause of the movement. Since a vacuum is causing the movement (vs. an explosion), Nick's right.

Comment: I like that you specify what is *not* necessary for a human to lift those crates.

Comment: @JBH No meaningful force can be imposed by a vacuum, because there is nothing there to exert that force.  The cause of motion is movement of the air particles which around room temperature would be moving around 500m/s combined with the fact that the vacuum contains no such particles to keep everything in equilibrium, so as soon as the room is exposed to vacuum the air molecules moving in its direction are no longer impeded by other air molecules moving the opposite direction and as this differential propagates, yes, there is a force behind the cargo of air molecules moving towards it.

Comment: @Michael You just made my point! Thank you! You're confusing the *mass that's causing the cargo to move* with the *conditions that cause the mass to move.* That same mass isn't causing the cargo to move before the exposure to a vacuum any more than it would before the presence of an explosion. [Obligatory XKCD](https://what-if.xkcd.com/6/) concerning the forces that can be imposed by the presence of a vacuum.

Comment: BTW, Nick. I removed the [tag:reality-check] tag. You're using it improperly. To summarize the tag wiki, the [tag:reality-check] tag's purpose is to check whether or not you're consistently using the rules of your world - not to test whether or not a real-world event is realistic. See the tag's wiki for more info.

Comment: anyway, define "suck". since that always requires a pressure differential, you'll find that it describes the situation perfectly.

Comment: @JBH I've always wanted someone to fact-check that XKCD - a vacuum does not exert force, so it would only rise based on buoyancy in the surrounding air. However, glass is ~1000x more dense than air, and my back-of-the-envelope calculations suggest that a glass cup would have to be literally razor thin to be light enough.

Comment: @RobWatts While the basic physics presented in that XKCD are correct, the fish-tale quality exaggeration is a hallmark for the author. See, for example, [Relativistic Baseball](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/). It's part of the comedy (along with "Hey, free glass!"). My basic complaint with Michael is that mass doesn't leave a pressurized space ship via breach using the word "blown" anymore than orange juice isn't "blown" into your mouth through a straw. When the pressure differential is in front of the moving gas, it's "sucked." when the differential is behind the moving gas, it's "blown."

Comment: @JBH oh I agree that "suck" is semantically correct here. I do think that "blown" *could* be used here, and actually it might help people understand the situation better - it's like movie depictions of a depressurization event in an airplane where everything is sucked and sucked out vs reality where once enough air leaves it would be calm (though perhaps quite windy). Also in case anyone is interested, I did ask about it on [physics.se](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/711709/could-a-glass-cup-containing-a-vacuum-rise-into-the-air)

Comment: @RobWatts I learned as a marketer that changing people's perspective (e.g., their basic understanding of the difference between "suck" and "blown") is the most expensive and difficult way to achieve any goal possible. As for improving anyone's understanding of this post - let's be realistic. No it wouldn't. Michael was correct that his was a pedantic nitpick, which I was poking fun at because it was really pedantic and entirely a nitpick. (BTW, you already have one answer over at [physics.se] suggesting the XKCD is plausible!)

Comment: I actually reviewed the sentence and I think "blown out" would not convey what I meant. Might confuse people and give weird ideas about differing velocities and angles of departure of the lost items.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Very Widely separated**

Looking at a ridiculously dense but almost-plausible "crate", let's assume for ease of calculation a spherical container massing 10 tons (10^4 kg) with a radius of 1 m.  [Escape velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity) is around 0.0011 m/s, which would be trivially exceeded in a depressurisation event.  The practical upshot is that none of the objects ejected will start to clump together due to their own gravity, the only situation in which they may be collected would be through capture in the gravity well of an at least planet-sized object in their path - exceedingly unlikely for a random point in space.

Even if there is a very gentle depressurisation with only a 5 m/s difference in velocity between a crate with a beacon and the un-beaconed backpack with a treasure map that was sitting next to it, after one year the two objects will be 5 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 = 157,680,000 m apart, or about half a light-second.  With a greater difference in velocity (possibly up to an order of magnitude higher) and/or multiple years, the search sphere will probably be many light-seconds across.  Being able to locate more beacons might help define the sphere, but only if the objects with beacons were ejected with similar velocities to the un-beaconed objects.  If the crates are all relatively dense then they will not give much useful information about where less dense objects that had a higher velocity imparted to them may have ended up.

The detection capabilities of the searchers are not specified, but it would take extremely powerful radars and/or sensitive infra-red detectors to detect an piece of debris that has had years to radiate its residual heat away into space within a search sphere that large.  Unless the "dollar value" of the lost objects is truly enormous, the expense of deploying large number of ships for a prolonged period probably exceeds the value of the objects.

Comment: A gravity well is indeed random for a truly random point in space. But where and when do accidents (likely) happen? Very likely NOT during the completely eventless travel through empty space, so there is a massive statistical bias for a gravity well to be nearby

Answer (score 18):

## Straps to the rescue

Gravity, as a force, is not good at holding boxes together. A much better force for holding things together is rope, or their thinner, broader cousin, straps.

When loading things into a vehicle that may experience sudden shifts in trajectory, it is wise to use Many Straps.

[image]

When transporting loose cargo, it is wise to use a large lattice of ropes, called a ‘net’ to hold them together.

[image]

Frequently, smaller objects will be palletized and lashed together:

[image]

This is true regardless of the size of the object. It’s basic safety. I wouldn’t get into the bed of a moving pickup with a loose 55 gallon drum. The idea of being in a spaceship cargo bay  with one is nightmarish. Imagine a gerbil in a rock tumbler. The cargo in these ships is going to be thoroughly strapped and tied together, and will remain so post depressurization.

Not only is this practical and safe, it’s also traditional and cinematic.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 because this renders the question moot by using a common shipping technique that, with very rare exception (like a few frames later in that James Bond movie when he cuts a couple 'o straps and the drugs start falling free) will ensure that the cargo doesn't spread out over multiple year's time. Add the trackers as stated by the OP, and it's suddenly economical to retrieve it. Cheers!

Answer (score 15):

Depends on the depressurization event

Did it effectively act as a jet blowing things all the same direction?

Or did it act as an explosion sending things every which way?

Time factors are important.  They will continue to move at their ejection speed, and this will spread them apart from the explosive route.  (Gravity will not be significant.)

On the other hand, they will be moving slowly enough that a culture that moves in outer space may consider them "close" at distances we would not.

Consider not only beacons but whether the other items can be detected by radar.  Bright, metallic items are better than matte plastics.

Answer (score 9):

**Calculable.**

There are images of the depressurization event taken from the ship in question.  One can see the items at a known time and see them again at a later known time.  From these two images one can calculate the trajectory of each crate, assuming that at the time of these two images crates do not touch each other again.

Given the trajectory of the ship and gravitational influences in this area of space, your AI uses these two images to calculate the trajectory of each crate and the position of each at any future time.

In this story as I imagine it, there is one outlier crate that is far away from the rest.   The salvage ops person questions the AI about this and views the image data.  No question:  that crate was moving faster than all the rest.  Some crates have contents unlisted on the cargo manifest and this was one of them.  The ops person decides to get that one first.

Comment: hopefully the cameras are outside of the ship and can see both moments in time as having happened after the depressurization event was complete, otherwise forces would still be acting on the objects and their final directional and trajectory harder to compute.

Comment: @Michael - maybe the images are from outside the ship?   Perhaps a rescue ship took pictures once it got the distress call.

Comment: One camera inside might record in what sequence the objects departed through the hatch or hole, and have better resolution to identify specific objects. Other cameras outside or from nearby ships would record trajectory info. And all cameras would be video, giving multiple points (frames) with which to describe the velocity vector.

Answer (score 7):

Depends greatly on the tech available and the circumstances of the accident that the other posts point out. For some perspective: [Lunar Module Eagle on Apollo 11 when the crew re-boarded Columbia, the Eagle was abandoned in lunar orbit. Although its ultimate fate remains unknown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Module_Eagle#:%7E:text=After%20the%20crew%20re%2Dboarded,still%20be%20in%20lunar%20orbit.) You can be sure that people have looked for Eagle in various ways, granted not exhaustively or systematically, but they haven't spotted anything for 53 years. It may not be there but math shows that it probably is, and people are still looking.

Comment: wait, so you're saying that there could be an object the size of a small house in Lunar orbit, but nobody looking for it has found it yet?

Comment: Correct! Perspective.

Answer (score 6):

**They will drift apart**

This is your basic simplification of chaos theory. The atmosphere in the compartment isn't actually homogeneous in its density. The various crates certainly aren't homogeneous in their density, nor identical in shape. Some are sitting against the floor, some on top of other containers (differences in friction). I could go on, but I suspect you get my point. It isn't simply the odds that they might drift together...

...they won't.

**Whether or not they drift widely depends on both time and velocity**

Whether or not years is a long time depends on the velocity of the containers when they left the ship. A massive cargo hold, something the volume of the [Empire State Building](https://www.esbnyc.com/sites/default/files/esb_fact_sheet_final_0.pdf)) would result in significant velocity, while something the size of a [Volkswgon beetle](https://www.edmunds.com/volkswagen/beetle/2018/features-specs/) would impart almost none at all. The higher the velocity, the greater the distance between the pieces.

**It also depends on where it happens, which you didn't specify**

As noted in my comment, the gravitational influence found midway between two galaxies is negligible and likely irrelevant to the conditions of the question. If this happened in or near planetary orbit, however, gravity becomes a *big deal,* especially over years. Did it happen in a nebula? It's not like slogging through a sand dune, but the higher and non-homogeneous density of the nebula gasses will have an effect. Did it happen to happen near the sweep of a pulsar? What if that sweep only caught some of the cargo? Where it happens is a big deal — especially as the location will determine whether or not it's practical (if even possible) to calculate their trajectories. If you're capable of knowing all the variables to that level of accuracy, just beam them back aboard.

**And you don't seem to worry about what's happening to the cargo**

That cargo is now exposed to the vacuum of space. Are the containers that well sealed? Can the contents handle the force of the containers tumbling? Are the containers shielded against various forms of radiation? How about heat if their lost in the neighborhood of a star? I can easily imagine the cargo being worthless on recovery — especially when it wouldn't be cost-efficient to build and use containers that guaranteed the safety of the cargo in any and all circumstances.

**But you're in luck! Some of the units have tracking**

Ignoring entirely the reality that tracking anything over a significant distance in space is complicated, your tracking can improve things by giving you a *cone of influence* where you can estimate the spread of the cargo.  That's a bonus!

**But the real question is, is all that worth it?**

Doesn't your insurance cover this? What could be so valuable that it would be worth the expense of dragging a ship through space to find this stuff? When cargo is lost overboard on Earth's seas, it's incredibly rare that anybody tries to find it.

**TL;DR**

Yes, they'll drift apart, and you probably need to assume they'll drift apart a lot.